# SqlCommand.ExecuteReader Fails to Report Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm executing a SQL command to create a new record in a database table and get the ID of the created record. However, there's a constraint error generated by the SQL command (uninitialized non-null field) which is not being picked up by the VB code. The code is roughly:-

```
connection = New SqlConnection(connection_string)
connection.Open()

sql_command = New SqlCommand(command) 'command = the SQL command to execute
sql_command.Connection = connection
sql_command.Parameters.AddRange(sql_parameters.ToArray()) ' sql_parameters is a parameter to the function

reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader()

If reader IsNot Nothing Then
    If reader.HasRows Then
        While reader.Read
            response_handler(reader, data) 'response handler is a callback which populates the data object
        End While
    End If

    reader.Close()
End If
```

The reader object is non-null but contains no data and no exception is generated. The SQL command is:-

```
insert into [table] ([column1], [column2], [column3], [column4]) 
output Inserted.[pk] 
values (@1, @2, @3, @4)
```

Executing the SQL statement using SQL Server Management Studio, I get the error:-

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'somecolumn', table 'tablename'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I have also added a handler for the `InfoMessage` event on the `SqlConnection` object but that doesn't get called, even when I set `FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors` to true.

Why am I not getting an error and what is the correct way to ensure the error is reported to VB?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I would not expect the exception to be thrown until the `reader.Read()` method is called, and it is never called because `HasRows` is false. What I am trying (unsuccessfully) to find is at what point `HasRows` is set in order to provide a proper answer. You could just skip the validation `If reader.HasRows Then..` since if it does not have rows you will never enter the `While reader.Read` loop (if there are no rows it will be false when it is first run).

Comment: @GarethD: Hmmm, I'll try removing the HasRows check and see if it starts to produce errors. I'll update the question when I've tried it (after the weekend)

Comment: Sidenote: delete the first to `If` statements. They do nothing.

Comment: @usr: yes, removing the two ifs did solve my problem - so much for defensive programming! Unfortunately, can't mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: I do not believe that solved your problem because those statements to nothing. You solved the problem some other way. This was a coincidence.

Comment: @usr: I think it was the HasRows call that was the problem, in that the response was an error and that there were no rows returned so HasRows would be, correctly, false. It's just a bit odd being forced to read data from something that you know has no data in order to get the error.

Comment: You're right! I always just thought that this was redundant but I was wrong. I think HasRows is bad style because the HasRows is like the enumerator pattern (MoveNext). It is better to use a common pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HasRows` call returns false if there is an error. That way you will never see the error. Remove both `If` statements. The null check is redundant, the other one suppresses errors.

Answer (score 0):

The severity level is 16 which does not interrupt the current session. If you want to throw a hard error you could add something like this directly after your insert...

```
If      @@Error <> 0
Begin   
        Raiserror('Constraint Error Encountered',20,1) With Log;
End
```

The security context will have to have sysadmin rights in order to perform the `RAISERROR WITH LOG`, but if you can't do this I'm sure there are other ways to throw a hard error. In any event a warning isn't going to throw an error to your VB code.

Comment: Severity level 16 is not considered information, Severitity level 10 is informational; [MSDN States](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937483%28v=sql.80%29.aspx): *Severity levels from 11 through 16 are generated by the user, and can be corrected by the user.*

Comment: I was looking at the same page, I just interpreted the non-session interrupting levels as "informational" since they don't throw an error, but I'll change the language as you are correct and this could be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how it works internally, but the property `HasRows` is set by a private method within the SqlDataReader class called something like `TryGetNextResult`, which uses a lot of try/catch blocks to set a boolean output parameter, so this method never throws any exception, or even provides any feedback about any errors. What I can't work out is exactly how it realises there will be errors without even attempting the insert, but it does.

With this sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT IDENTITY, A INT NOT NULL);
```

I ran:

```
string sql = @"INSERT T (A) OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.A VALUES (1);";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.HasRows); // True
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(1)); // 1
        }
    }
}
```

When I changed this to try and insert null, `reader.HasRows` was false, but by putting a breakpoint in I was able to test before reader.Read() was called, and this shows that the identity value of the table T was unchanged, so the reader can't be validating inserts by simply rolling back transactions. It is a mystery to me why a SqlDataReader is able to identify that this insert will fail before execution, but yet if the SQL is executed it will still attempt the insert before raising an error.

To further prove the behaviour I ran a similar test with a simple select command, and saw the same behaviour:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sql = @" SELECT Date = CAST(D AS DATE)
                    FROM    (VALUES
                                (1, '20130129'),
                                (2, '20130130'),
                                (3, '20130131'),
                                (4, '20130132')
                            ) t (A, D)
                    ORDER BY A;";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.HasRows); // false
            while (reader.Read()) // Exception
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again this shows, that somehow the SqlDataReader has picked up that there will be an error casting `20130132` to a date. If I remove this row from the SQL the `HasRows` property becomes true.

I realise this doesn't actually answer your question but it was too long for a comment, hopefully it will help a little, and/or maybe prompt somebody who knows a lot more about c# than me to add their own answer.